# How can I generate dynamic app routes from Flask?

Tags: python, opencv, flask

Say I have

```
@app.route('/video_feed/0')       
def video_feed0():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera(var1)), 
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/video_feed/1')       
def video_feed1():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera(var2)), 
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Where gen() is a generator that grabs a video frame from VideoCamera (opencv)

I would display it with:

```
<img id="bg" src="localhost:5000/video_feed/0">
and 
<img id="bg" src="localhost:5000/video_feed/1">
```

What is the best way to replicate this for arbitrary video sources, say with something like:

```
def createVidFeeds():
    video_feeds = [1,'192.168.1.233:8080/video']
    for index,item in enumerate(video_feeds):
        video_feed(index,item)  
createVidFeeds()
```

the enumerate() is there to give sort of a counter variable that I can then pass on to use in /video_feed/

I would expect it would look something like this:

```
def createVidFeeds():
    video_feeds = [1,'192.168.1.233:8080/video']
    for index,item in enumerate(video_feeds):
        video_feed(index,item)  
createVidFeeds()

@app.route('/video_feed/<num>')
def video_feed(num, arg):
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera(arg)),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary = frame')
```

but I haven't been able to get any of that to work.

now, I've heard a lot about `app.add_url_rule()` and I feel like that is the answer here, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around how I would implement that in my code.

Comment: why you don't make the createVidFeeds() into the vedio_feed dunction

Comment: something like this
@app.route("post/<identifier>")
def post(identifier):  # parameter name must match dynamic route parameter name
    the_post = get_from_database_by(identifier)
    response = make_response_from_entity(the_post)
    return response

Comment: @Ghassen I'm gonna try declaring that list from inside, and then with @app.route('/video_feed/<num>) i'll call video_feed(num) and then define feed_source = video_feed[num] so that the number of the video says which element to pass on to the VideoCamera. This isn't futureproof because the sources are still hard-coded  but it might work

Comment: try to pass the data hard coded as u said if it works we will search for a solution with dynamic data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
@app.route('/video_feed/<num>')       
def video_feed(num):
    video_feeds = [1,'http://**WEBCAM_IP**/video']
    fsrc = video_feeds[int(num)]
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera(fsrc)), 
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

it uses the number of the iteration to select from the list as suggested by @ghassen . There are a few problems with this, namely to add sources from the webpage I'll have to move the list outside. but it does work for now.

If someone can tell me how to iteratively display the videos in the HTML, that would be awesome, albeit outside the scope of the question.